# Use image library from Hammerspoon

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I'd like to use a more sophisticated graphics or GUI widget library in my Hammerspoon config file, in order to get user input and do more advanced drawing on the screen than Hammerspoon allows (as far as I can tell) by default.  I'm new to Lua and Hammerspoon, and so far I've been unable to figure out how to get this working.  (Simple drawing on-screen is not a problem, so examples of geometric shapes are not helpful.  I can do that already with no difficulty.)

I initially thought one of the Lua libraries designed for building games would have more than I could possibly need, and looked into love2d, but it did not appear to be possible to use with Hammerspoon in any straightforward manner.

To give two concrete examples of things I'd like to do:

1. I'd like to display a dialog box in which the user can enter two values, to specify how many rows and how many columns they want in their screen grid.  A native Cocoa dialog would be better, but something graphically drawn on screen with Lua would be fine, as long as the details of the image are abstracted away for me, and I can just define the text and fields and buttons in the dialog.
2. I'd like to draw a dotted-line rectangle with curved corners and a shadow around specified grid segments as a preview of where a window would be moved if the user completed a certain command.

There's a lot more, but anything that allows me to do those things should allow me to do anything else I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't yet have a good answer to generating dialog boxes, although it is possible to do it with AppleScript, which you can call from Hammerspoon with hs.osascript.

As for drawing things like dotted-line rectangles, we can't currently do that, but if you'd like to file an issue on our GitHub project, it's something we can look at for a future release :)